# need to decouple the ng-model and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, decouple

I'm new to Angularjs and I need some help. my real situation is about the ng-model and the usage of the filter: my ng-model is linked to a scope variable, and this variable is used by a filter. As soon as the ng-model detects the change, the filter kicks in, but I need to apply the filter when user clicks on a Save button. 
My filter is defined as $scope.filterFunction= function ( item ) on the controller. I tried to use a fake ng-model to take the changes on the control, but the original display on this control is empty, if I use the right ng-model then the filter kicks in automatically. Has anyone had experience on decoupling the ng-model and the filter ?   Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: put code or any reference so we are able to help you. [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You wouldn't need to use the filter at all then. Once the user clicks "save" trigger a function that runs the same code as the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. My story turned out to be on a different path. Instead of working against the ng-model and filter behavior combined, I ended up having flag when the client pulls the initial value(if value==0), the filter works on this flag(=true) only. This way, the value change is not triggering filter, when user clicks on the Save button, the updated value result in flag(==false), Wola! the filter kicks in.  I hope this helps if anyone in the similar situation. If there is a need to work against the default behavior of a framework, usually there must be a different way, a simpler way.